# How to apply custom styles for taking a screenshot of DOM in Reactjs with html2canvas

Tags: css, reactjs, screenshot, html2canvas

I have a web application where I need to take a screenshot of the particular DIV element with some styles. But I need those styles has to be applied in screenshot also. How can I achieve this?

Below is my piece of code:

```
printDocument(divid) {
    const input = document.getElementById(divid);
    html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        this.saveAs(imgData, "screenshot.png");
    });
}
```

I have applied some styles for web purpose. I need these styles has to be applied for screenshot also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dom-to-image`(https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) in this context, it helps you apply the styles in image.